# How To Jira Resolution IDs from with Python Jira Library?

Tags: python, jira

Right now I'm trying to get all the resoultion ids for a given project. I'm using the jira python library found here: https://jira.readthedocs.io/ and a longer version of the documentation here: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/jira/latest/jira.pdf

The code is as follows:

```
option: {
    'server': url
}

jira_client = JIRA(options, token_auth=token)

response = jira_client.resolutions()
print(response)
```

This returns a list with a single element and that element is a single string as seen here:

`[<JIRA Resolution: name='Done', id='10000'>, <JIRA Resolution: name="Won't Do", id='10001'>, <JIRA Resolution: name='Duplicate', id='10002'>, <JIRA Resolution: name='Declined', id='10003'>, <JIRA Resolution: name='Cancelled', id='10100'>, <JIRA Resolution: name='Transferred', id='10200'>, <JIRA Resolution: name='Known Error', id='10300'>, <JIRA Resolution: name='Hardware failure', id='10301'>, <JIRA Resolution: name='Software failure', id='10302'>]`

I'm attempting to parse the code, so I can get the resolution_name and resolution_id for each entry and put it into a list of dictionaries, but I'm at a loss.  Right now I currently have:

```
r_temp_list = str(resolutions).replace('<','').replace(">", "").replace("JIRA Resolution: ", "")
print(r_temp_list)

[name='Done', id='10000', name="Won't Do", id='10001', name='Duplicate', id='10002', name='Declined', id='10003', name='Cancelled', id='10100', name='Transferred', id='10200', name='Known Error', id='10300', name='Hardware failure', id='10301', name='Software failure', id='10302']
```

I attempted to use the python requests library, and have received a successful response, and can parse the information that way.  But for the sake of resources and logic, I would like to stick to one method  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hey @outsideyam are you using Jira Cloud?
If so the following will give you what you want:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

url = "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/resolution"

auth = HTTPBasicAuth("email@example.com", "<api_token>")

headers = {
   "Accept": "application/json"
}

response = requests.request(
   "GET",
   url,
   headers=headers,
   auth=auth
)

print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, 
separators=(",", ": ")))
```

The output should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "self": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/resolution/1",
    "id": "10000",
    "description": "A fix for this issue is checked into the tree and tested.",
    "name": "Fixed"
  },
  {
    "self": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/resolution/3",
    "id": "10001",
    "description": "This is what it is supposed to do.",
    "name": "Works as designed"
  }
]
```

The full docs are here - https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-resolutions/#api-rest-api-3-resolution-get

I have a project that might help with some python/Jira operations - https://github.com/dren79/JiraScripting_public

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue and find the way how to extract it correct please check:

```
option: {
  'server': url
}
jira_client = JIRA(options, token_auth=token)

response = jira_client.resolutions()
for r in response:
  print("Resolution name "+r.name, " ID: "+r.id)
```

The resolution is object with attributes name and id and you can access it via api call

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).